# Changing carriers and sims - how do I know if the new network will work?

Tags: sim-card, sim-unlocking

My family is considering switching to T-Mobile, and I would like to bring my current Droid 4 with me. I have already stopped by a local T-Mobile store to see if their sim would work. The phone displayed the list of available mobile networks, but I could not make a call. Is that because the sim was not registered to my phone, or because the phone could not access the network properly?

Note, I am aware that a stock droid 4 is locked out of US GSM usage - as far as I can tell I overwrote the NV data to allow this.

Comment: If the SIM they gave you to test in the store did not work, then I would be skeptical that it's properly unlocked for domestic GSM. It seems unlikely that the rep would give you a SIM to test with if they knew it wasn't going to work without "registering" it, although I guess you could try going back and talking to someone else. Ordinarily, though, you can move a SIM between supported phones without any real fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Good choice (T-Mobile). If your phone is unlocked you should be able to use your device with most carriers, especially the ones who activate service with a SIM card.

It's most likely because it's not registered yet, I wouldn't see any reason otherwise.

**Update**

I'll agree with Eldrerathis here. It's possible that the device cannot connect to the network correctly.

Comment: Any sources or references on that information? I've never heard of a SIM failing to work because it wasn't "registered" to the phone. I know I've moved my SIM between 3 or 4 different phones at this point, and all of them worked instantly. Plus it would be kind of odd for the T-Mobile rep to give him a SIM for testing if it had no possibility of working.

Comment: Sorry about that, Eldrerathis. I read the whole thing in a completely different context. No, it'd definitely and most probably be because the device isn't able to find and connect to the network properly, and your answer is most feasible.